# Remove additional space in the div containing the list

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML here. I have been trying to design a survey form for practice. The code is available at this link: https://codepen.io/akshaykumar2002/pen/KGEVjB?editors=1100

When I try to add a list to a div element (used as an inline-block), I see that there are extra spaces added above and below the list. I am not sure how to remove these spaces.

I have added colors to the div (red) and the list elements (green). Here's the screenshot below:[The image with the div(red) and the list(green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KItq6.png)

Here's the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left"><label id="language-label">Languages know<br>(Select all that apply):</label></div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul id="preference" style="list-style: none;">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="C">C</input></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="Java">Java</input></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the corresponding CSS snippet:

```
.row {
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#preference {
  background-color: white;
}
li {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
}
```

Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove the red spaces that are added on top and bottom of your list, just simply add margin:0; to the #preference

```
#preference {
margin: 0;
background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Duy. I was able to figure that out due to another previous answer. However, any idea why that red space was added in the first place? I see that it works just fine in other scenarios, though.

Comment: It is inherited from UL element.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you gave `.row` a margin of 1px to all sides.
Change `.row` to:

```
.row {
  margin: 0px 1px;
}
```

The first property is for top & bottom, the second for left and right.

Comment: I want to remove that extra space within the div that is red in color above and below the list that is green in color. Not the space between rows but the extra space  (red in color) within the div with class="right" containing the list with id="preference". In simple terms, I want the list to occupy the complete div without leaving any extra space at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add "display: inline-flex;margin-top: 2px;margin-bottom: 2px"

```
Old:
      <ul id="preference" style="list-style: none;">

New:
      <ul id="preference" style="list-style: none;display: inline-flex;margin-top: 2px;margin-bottom: 2px">
```

https://codepen.io/shamshersandhu/pen/RedxrX

Comment: You can remove the "display:inline-flex", if you don't want those on the same line.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sam. But any idea, why such space was introduced? After all, I didn't add any margins.